# C# Custom Logger - Best way to capture sending object

Tags: c#, object, logging, system.diagnostics

I am attempting to build (for learning purposes) my own event logger; I am not interested in hearing about using a non-.net frameworks instead of building my own as I am doing this to better understand .net.

The idea is to have an event system that I can write out to a log file and/or pull from while inside the program.  To do this I am creating an `LogEvent` class that will be stored inside of a `Queue<LogEvent>`.

I am planning on using the following fields in my `LogEvent` class:

```
private EventLogEntryType _eventType //enum: error, info, warning...
private string _eventMessage
private Exception _exception
private DateTime _eventTime
```

What I am not sure is the best way to capture the object that caused the event to be called.  I thought about just doing a `private Object _eventObject;` but I am thinking that is not thread safe or secure.

Any advice on how to best store the object that called the event would be appreciated.  I am also open to any other suggestions you may have.

Thanks, Tony

Comment: I also want to mention that _eventMessage or _exception in required; both can be added, but only one is needed.

Comment: What's your reasoning behind wanting to store the object that called the event? If you are going to simple use a `.ToString()` on the object for log message creation, you would be better off storing the `.ToString()` value.

Comment: @Jastill I second that, especially in the case of an exception.  I would take the exception.ToString() and do a recursive append with the inner exceptions.  Your EventLogEntryType will let you know if it is an exception or not.

Comment: @Jastill - I thought about that, and I may end up doing that.  The reasoning behind wanting to store the object inside my program I could have a method that looks at the log and then calls program specific data from the object.  Something like:

`if (eventObject.getType().equals(typeof(myObjectType))){ return ((myObjectType)eventObject).CustomField; }`

Comment: Keeo an eye on performance. As your host application grows, you will start to gather more and more messages per second. Doing type checking is not the most ideal way of making sure things go to the write way. in your example I would still be storing a `string` and when calling the event use `myObject.CustomField.ToString()` as a parameter.

Comment: @JefferyKhan - I want to store the exception as an `Exception` for the same reason noted above, in the logWriter portion of my Project it converts it over to a string, writes it to a files and removes it from the queue.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols - I can tell you we started out with the above approach when the application was really small. When we moved the logger to another assembly and finally to another process (outside of IIS all together) it took us A LOT of time to get rid of the IIS context and such exception object passing around, etc.

Comment: Also, if you pass the object around, and it's a ref type, i.e. not immutable, you can make a bug near-impossible to find, in a case where you reuse the variable in a loop, for instance.

Comment: @EladLachmi -- Are you referring to passing in the actual object or passing/storing the exception? I see the point on the object and I will be going with the string method for that, But it seems to me storing the exception would be better than storing an exception string because of the amount of detail available in an exception.  Thoughts?

Comment: @AnthonyNichols - I was reffering to the actual object. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, nothing wrong with writing your own. There are some good frameworks our there, but sometimes you reach the point where some bizarre requirement gets you rolling your own, I've been there anyway...
I don't think you should be using text messages. After doing this type of logging in several projects, I have come the the conclusion that the best approach is to have a set of event types (integer IDs) with some type of extra information field.
You should have an enum of `LogEvetTypes` that looks something like this:

```
public enum LogEventTypes
{
    //1xxx WS Errors
    ThisOrThatWebServiceError = 1001,

    //2xxx DB access error


    //etc...
}
```

This, from my experience will make your life much easier when trying to make use of the information you logged. You can also add an `ExtraInformation` field in order to provide event instance specific information.

As for the object that caused the event, I would just use something like `typeof(YourClass).ToString();`. If this a custom class you created, you can also implement a `ToString` override that will name sense in your logging context.

**Edit:** I am adding several details I wrote about in the comments, since I think they are important. Passing objects, which are not immutable, by ref to service methods is generally not a good idea. You might reassigne the same variable in a loop (for example) and create a bug that is near-impossible to find. Also, I would recommend doing some extra work now to decouple the logging infrastructure from the implementation details of the application, since doing this later will cause a lot of pain. I am saying this from my own very painful experience.

Comment: To extend on @elad-lachmi's `ToString` override. if you are rolling all your own classes, you could potentially create an iLogInformation interface with a `.LogInfo()` method.

Comment: @Jastill - That's true, but was not an option in my projects. If you are building all your objects from scratch, you can definitely have them all implement some king of logging interface.

Comment: I like the idea on using the .LogInfo() -- but I might also want to user this for other projects or with objects that don't contain that code.  My thought on that would be to user a Try/Catch statement, is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe extension methods to support objects you cannot alter.